# Get query name inside database (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a database with multiple query objects inside of it, I am trying to execute all of them from visual studio but to do so I need the name of each query.
Is there any way to get the name of all the queries inside a database, from within visual studio?

Comment: Search about OleDb.Connection.GetSchema.

Comment: Are you talking about Views?

Comment: If you mean QueryDef objects and running a program created in VS rather than using VS directly, there seems to be code to do that in the [QueryDef object (DAO) documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydef-object-dao).

Comment: Steve, the GetSchema has only been useful the get the list of 'Table' or 'Make Table Query' objects but I haven't been successful to extract the name of 'Select Query' type objects. This is the code I am using for that:
        restrictions(3) = "View"
        Tables = cn.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions)

Comment: Andrew, do you know how I can use the QueryDef on vb.net? Because I get a Type 'QueryDef' is not defined, error when I try to use it

Comment: SELECT MSysObjects.Name
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE type = 5

Comment: @Fernando If you [add a reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2017) to "Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine Object Library" (you might have a different version number) and then use `Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao` at the top of the code, it will recognise `QueryDef`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to print all the query names into a ListBox using QueryDef object as Andrew suggested, below is the code I used:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao
Private Sub UpdateList(PathDB As String, List As ListBox)
    Dim db As Database
    Dim qdfLoop As QueryDef
    Dim DAOBEngine As New DBEngine()
    'Old list is cleared
    List.Items.Clear()
    'Connection to the database is created
    db = DAOBEngine.OpenDatabase(PathDB, False, False, "")
    'Each query on the database is added to the ListBox
    For Each qdfLoop In db.QueryDefs
        List.Items.Add(qdfLoop.Name)
    Next
    'Connection to the database is closed
    db.Close()
End Sub
```